# Partial derivatives of $\displaystyle g(x,y)=f(x^n+y^n,x^n-y^n)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Given the function
$$g(x,y)=f(x^n+y^n,x^n-y^n)$$
I have to show that
$$\frac{1}{nx^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)+\frac{1}{ny^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y)=0$$

If $u=x^n+y^n$ and $v=x^n-y^n$, then
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=nx^{n-1},\quad\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=ny^{n-1}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=nx^{n-1},\quad\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-ny^{n-1}$$
Then
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=nx^{n-1}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)$$
In the same way
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=ny^{n-1}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{nx^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)+\frac{1}{ny^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=2\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\neq0$$
What is wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, your work is correct

Comment: Maybe there is some additional condition ?

Comment: @zkutch no, there isn't.

Comment: Your work is correct. Where is this problem from?

Comment: @K.defaoite a friend asked me to help him.

Comment: It looks like $u=y^n-x^n$ should have been in the argument for $f(u,v)$.

Comment: Can you ask your friend about source - author/title - of question?